# jquery multiselect widget not posting empty when nothing selected on ajax submit

Tags: jquery, yii, multi-select

Hieee

Am using http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget plugin..

Am using yii framework for my project

I have nearly 12 multiselect widgets in my view file like..

```
<div class="multi_primary" id="one_primary">

                    <?php 
                     $htmlOptions = array('id'=>'relation1','multiple' => 'true');
                    echo CHtml::dropDownList('PrimaryRelation_2[]',$list_relations,$htmlOptions);
                      ?>
                </div>
```

am using ajax submit for submitting the form...

When am selected something in multi select widget and ajax submitting it posting the value fine like

```
PrimaryRelation_2[] 1,2
```

But when am submitting the form with out selecting any value in multi select widget it is not posting the field name and value.. at least it should post the empty value..

Tell me the changes what i have to do in multi select widget to post empty value when nothing is selected..

Thank you...

Comment: Try to use `'prompt'=>'My default value'` or `'empty'=>'my value'` in your htmlOptions. Should work like you need. Or check in Controller for existance or values in POST your arrays.

Comment: am using prompt like this   <div class="multi_primary" id="one_primary">
                     
                        <?php 
                         $htmlOptions = array('id'=>'relation1','multiple' => 'true','prompt'=>'value');
                        echo CHtml::dropDownList('PrimaryRelation_2[]','',$list_relations,$htmlOptions);
                          ?>
                    </div>                                                                  when value is not selected it is not posting the empty value, when value is selected it is posting the empty value..

Comment: Try `empty`. It works for me. Empty multiselects pass to post like `Lists[state]` and not empty like `Lists[state][] AK Lists[state][] AL`. Just check in your controller for `isset` and `!=''`

Comment: for me if nothing is selected it is not posting empty value.. and i tried isset it is working, but i have more than 12 multi select widgets in my view.. any other solution thank you.. for the cooperation

Comment: it it difficult to use isset for more no of fields,

Comment: not really. If it pass like field_1,field_2 and so on thats not hard. Use `for($i=0;$i<12;$i++) if (isset($_POST['field_'.$i])&&($_POST['field_'.$i]!='')) do what you need`

Comment: I found one solution for this..  on page load                                                                 jQuery('.multi_primary select option:first-child').prop("selected", true);                                   am forcingly selecting the first option ..... But i want to hide the first option , am not able to do... Can you give the solution for this thank very much inersa

Comment: Maybe your plugin makes something wrong. I just check it in controller and use empty option. Idk why you dont want to do like i typed and trying to invent bycicle. And why you have 12? multiselects on page, sorry but its crazy. How you'll write it to database or what is this? (if filters you will need to form arrays anyway). So just go in cycle and check for existance. Its not so hard. If these are values for DB you'll need to serialize them. If they are quite big its 12 text fields. Can you imagine this table size and selects with atleast 1m records?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a Custom JSControl for multiselect. In this multiselect control you can handle your condition easily.You can add this JSControlfile on your Head tag after your JqueryUI autocomplete file.

Once you create a custom JSControl, you just add this control on your page load at the desire position. the reaming part is done by the control itself.

the control should be look like this :

```
// Constructor of the control
function AutoCompleteMultiSelect(controlId,label,containerID,tabIndex){
    this.ControlID = controlId;
    this.Label = label;
    this.ContainerID = containerID;
    this.TabIndex = tabIndex;
    this.RegisteredCallbacks = Object();
}

// function for registering event callback
AutoCompleteMultiSelect.prototype.RegisterEventCallback = function (event, callback) {
    this.RegisteredCallbacks[event] = callback;
}

  // function to add the control on the given container.
   AutoCompleteMultiSelect.prototype.AddAutoCompleteMultiSelect = function () 
{
      var tabIndex = 'tabindex="' + this.TabIndex + '"';
      var controlHTML = '<div>';
      controlHTML += '<h2> ' + this.Label+ ' </h2>';
      controlHTML += '<div>';
      controlHTML += '<span>';
      controlHTML += '<input '+ tabIndex +' type="text" id="' + this.ControlID  + '" name="' + this.Label+ '" />';
     controlHTML += '<input type="hidden" id="' + this.ControlID  + '_Value" name="' + this.displayName + '" value="0"/>';
    controlHTML += '</span></div></div>';

    // Add the control into container
    $(controlHTML).appendTo('#' + this.ContainerID);

    var that = this;

    that.loadLookUp();

    $("#" + this.ControlID).blur(function () {
      if (that.RegisteredCallbacks['onblur'] != undefined) {
         that.RegisteredCallbacks['onblur'](this.ControlID);
      }
    });

}

AutoCompleteMultiSelect.prototype.loadLookUp = function () {

 $("#" + this.ControlID).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function (request, response) {
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            // your service call
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.Name,
                        value: item.SQLPrimarykey
                    };
                }));
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // your error come
            } 
    },
    focus: function () {
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {

        var terms = split(this.value);

        var length = terms.length

        if (terms.indexOf(ui.item.label) == -1) {

            terms.pop();

            terms.push(ui.item.label);

            terms.push("");

            this.value = terms.join(", ");

            var value = this.value.substring(0, this.value.lastIndexOf(','));

            $("#" + this.ControlID).val(value);

            //Handle Values
            var valuesStr = $("#" + this.ControlID+ "_Value").val();

            if (length == 1) {
                valuesStr = "";
            }

            var values;

            if (valuesStr != "") {
                values = split(valuesStr);
            }
            else {
                values = new Array();
            }

            values.push(ui.item.value);
            values.push("");

            valuesStr = values.join(", ");
            valuesStr = valuesStr.substring(0, valuesStr.lastIndexOf(','));

            $("#" + this.ControlID+ "_Value").val(valuesStr);
        } else {
            var sv = $("#" + this.ControlID).val();
            sv = sv.substring(0, sv.lastIndexOf(','));
            $("#" + this.ControlID).val(sv);

            var valuesStr = $("#" + this.ControlID+ "_Value").val();
            valuesStr = valuesStr.substring(0, valuesStr.lastIndexOf(','));
            $("#" + this.ControlID+ "_Value").val(valuesStr);
        }

        return false; // Prevent the widget from inserting the value.       
    }
});
$("#" + this.ControlID).bind("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
}
function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}
```

}

Now you can Just Add your control on your HTML Page.

```
var control = new AutoCompleteMultiSelect(yourControlID,yourControlLabel,yourContainerName,tabIndexoftheControl);
control.AddAutoCompleteMultiSelect();
```

you can add this control as many time you want to your page.

when this control onchange event fires and the value and text is set into input and hiddenField.

you can just get value and text like this.

```
var value = $("#yourControlName_Value").val();
var text = $("#yourControlName").val();
```

and use this value for further use.

thanks,